# how can I get all constants defined in a single php file to an array?

Tags: php

how can I get all constants defined in a single php file to an array?
this is a php file with constants defining. 
I want to get all the constants in this page to an array;
how can I do the job?

```
<?php 
/**
 *  hello wolrd
 ----------------------------------------
 */

define('HELLO_WORLD','hello world');
define('GOOD_BOOD','
    very good
');
define(
    'JY_CREDITS_HTML',
    '
        <p>hello wrold</p>
        <div class="good">
            <span>world</span>
        </div>

    '
);
// define('META_KEY','Wat adidi');

define('XXX',"xxx")

/* 
    hello world
 */
?>
```

the result should be

```
<?php 
    $result=array(
        'HELLO_WORLD' => 'hello wrold',
        'GOOD_BOOD' => 'very good',
        'JY_CREDITS_HTML' =>'....',
        'XXX'=>'xxx'
    );

 ?>
```

Comment: [PHP MANUAL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print_r( get_defined_constants(true)['user'] );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
print_r(get_defined_constants(true));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use something like:-

```
define('HELLO_WORLD','hello world');

define('GOOD_BOOD','
    very good
');

define(
'JY_CREDITS_HTML',
'
    <p>hello wrold</p>
    <div class="good">
        <span>world</span>
    </div>

'
);

define('XXX',"xxx");
$result = get_defined_constants(true);
if(isset($result['user'])){
    $result = $result['user']; //just incase there are no user constants set.
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output:-

```
array (size=4)
  'HELLO_WORLD' => string 'hello world' (length=11)
  'GOOD_BOOD' => string '
    very good
' (length=17)
  'JY_CREDITS_HTML' => string '
    <p>hello wrold</p>
    <div class="good">
        <span>world</span>
    </div>

' (length=92)
  'XXX' => string 'xxx' (length=3)
```

See here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php

Answer (score 1):

```
include('hello_world.php');   
$constants = get_defined_constants();
```

Include() is not required when working in the same script as the constants.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   $user_def_cnst=get_defined_constants(true)['user'];
   print_r($user_def_cnst);
?>
```